# Binary field in openerp

Tags: button, binary

I want to create Upload document in my module. I am creating Upload process using Binary type field. It is showing three buttons (select, save as, clear). Those three buttons are executing same process (upload documents only). "clear" buttons should be clear Field. What do i do?

python:

```
'file_upload': fields.binary('Documents')
```

xml:

```
<field name="file_upload"/>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

These three button are doing only upload process.
I want it are doing separate process.

can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to move on to the 'Save As' Button by pressing TAB. Then press ENTER.

It seem's that the buttons are doing their jobs correctly, but the 'Save As' Button is not touchable for your mouse pointer.

We have found that there is an unvisible element that obviously shall overlaying the 'Select' Button only, but it covers the 'Save As' Button as well. So you are always clicking on this unvisible tag.